# Windows launch second RStudio?

Tags: windows, rstudio

I set a web scraper to run in [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/), but now I'd like to do something else and I can't. No matter how I try to launch RStudio, it keeps sending me back to the open program. How can I run a second, independent RStudio?

Comment: Just so I can get an answer, what is Rstudio?

Comment: @Mrfunny744 Rstudio is a IDE for the statistical programming language, R.

Comment: There is also an R-studio is an undeleting program. So you should clarify your question with what you wrote in comment.  You could include screenshots too.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 8 and I can open multiple RStudio sessions. Probably it depends on the version of Windows you are using. Google search on "rstudio multiple sessions" shows that usually it is possible. So probably more details would be necessary to answer your question.

You could try to install RStudio in two different folders and run each of them separately.